# How can I set the position in Pronterface?

Tags: software, pronterface

I'm in the process of building a 3D printer and have all the stepper motors wired up and the controller connected to the computer running pronterface.

I can move each axis and also send g-code to the printer.

Now **how can I define the current position to be the 0/0/0 position?**
I'd like to move the printer into a position where I think should be the zero position and define it as such in pronterface somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> G92 X0 Y0 Z0

tells the printer that the current position is (0,0,0).

Answer (score 3):

There's a handy list of G0-codes at http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code -- though the list is too big to be convenient for finding a code if you're not already sure what it's called... :(

Comment: Ctrl+F is your friend. :)